# Gulp-bless freezing when used with scss sourcemaps

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I am unable to use gulp-sourcemaps together with gulp-bless. Gulp-bless just freezes on watch, whenever sorucemaps are included. Each of them works fine alone. Anyone had a similar problem?

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./css/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(plumber())
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
      .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'compressed'
    }).on('error', function(error) {
        this.emit('end');
        notify({
            title: "SASS ERROR",
            message: "line " + error.line + " in " + error.file.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '') + "\n" + error.message
        }).write(error);
    }))
      .pipe(autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 3 versions'] }))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'));
});

gulp.task('splitCss', function() {
    return gulp.src('./css/style.css')
      .pipe(bless())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/ie'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./css/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('./css/style.css', ['splitCss']);
}
```